# Python3 JsonDecodeError Expecting Delimiter

Tags: python, json, sockets

I am trying to write a Python script that can access the Cgminer RPC that works in Python3.

I have got it to work except for this one specific command. Everytime I run it, it returns the following:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "newapi.py", line 61, in <module>
  enc = json.loads(returned)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
  obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 222 (char 221)
```

I have tried multiple methods that I have found in other answers, including using:

```
.replace('//' /r'//')
```

and the likes, but none of the replace codes let `json.loads` parse the file.

Here is my original code:

```
import socket
import logging as log
import json
import sys
class CgminerAPI(object):
    """ Cgminer RPC API wrapper. """
    def __init__(self, host='192.168.86.31', port=4028):
        self.data = {}
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def command(self, command, arg=None):
        """ Initialize a socket connection,
        send a command (a json encoded dict) and
        receive the response (and decode it).
        """
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        try:
            log.debug("connecting to %s:%d", self.host, self.port)
            sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
        except (socket.error, e):
            log.error("unable to connect to %s:%d", self.host, self.port)
            sys.exit(1)

        try:
            payload = {"command": command}
            jspay = json.dumps(payload)
            encpay = jspay.encode('utf-8')
            if arg is not None:
                # Parameter must be converted to basestring (no int)
                payload.update({'parameter': unicode(arg)})

            sock.send(encpay)
            received = self._receive(sock)

        finally:
            sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            sock.close()

        return received

    def _receive(self, sock, size=4096):
        msg = ''
        while 1:
            chunk = sock.recv(size).decode('utf-8')
            if chunk:
                msg += chunk
            else:
                break
        return msg

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        def out(arg=None):
            return self.command(attr, arg)
        return out

miner = CgminerAPI()
returned = (miner.command('stats'))
returned = returned.replace('\x00','')
enc = json.loads(returned)
print(enc)
```

Comment: share what the characters are between `~215-225` and I bet there's probably `}` followed by a `{` without the necessary `,` between them

Comment: Thank you, I ended up finding that. What I did to fix it (since I can't edit the cgminer api) is i used 
`foutput = (returned[:221] + "," +returned[221:])`
I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it or not but it seems like it is working.